# Encrypt a file using java but Decrypt the file from Command line (terminal)

Tags: java, android, encryption, terminal

How to implement 
Encrypting the log file using java code in android programmatically and decrypting the log file from terminal(Command Prompt).

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of en/decryption command line tools so you could use one for the decryption as long as on java side you are doing the encryption using the same algorithm. There is also quite a few java libraries that could do the encryption for you. Keep in mind that some encryption algorithms need to encrypt the full text, so you can encrypt each message and add it to the log, you may have to decrypt the log add the message and then encrypt the whole thing again. I am not sure if there is a more performant way to do it without revealing the log content.

Comment: please understand the question that i Posted. Actually i want to encrypt a file using java code and also I need to decrypt the file from command promt eg : actual file - textLog.txt , Now i need to decrypt -  eg :" terminal command "  textlog.text. I want the algorithm as well as it should work when decrypted from command prompt

Comment: Usually logs are generated as the application is running. If you just want to encrypt a file after it is been generated using java I am pretty sure you can just google that and find your answer. As for the terminal part you mean using a terminal on android phone ? or are you planning on sending the encrypted file somewhere and then view on it on a pc windows/linux... In case it is the latter then my previouse answer still stands.

Comment: Absolutely @anthony yaghi. I want to view it(i.e., decrypt using terminal command) on PC(ubuntu).